# In a clip, what does the "Stem Length" mean?

Tags: trim, plastic, fastener, measurement

I am currently trying to find replacement fender clips for my car. The OEM part numbers are 01553-09321 (Nissan), 90044-68320 (Toyota), and MR328954 (Mitsubishi).

I have the hole size (7.7mm), and overall length (22mm), which were measured with a calliper. How does this relate to "Stem Length"? That is, what exactly is the stem length?

The following picture as an example - am I correct in assuming that the stem length is 9mm?
[image]

Comment: Great visual, btw ... helped tremendously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, 9 is the stem length in the graphic you have pictured.

Comment: Ayup, that would be a true statement. :D

Comment: Super! So why do people list the stem length almost exclusively on parts? Is it simply because it's only the stem that really matters, and not the overall length?

Comment: @Nick Pretty much. It's expected that it going to stick out of the top of the panel, and they make that as low as reasonably possible.